# Drupal 7 - Ajax and Bootstrap - Rerender Main Menu on Login

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

How can I rerender the main menu in Drupal after an Ajax Login?

I already tried the following (generating the return value in my PHP Ajax Controller):

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
$returnValue = drupal_render(menu_tree_output($tree));
```

However this will not include the Bootstrap specific class names. It basically just returns a minimalistic menu structure without anything added by the theme.

In the Bootstrap theme, the menu is rendered like this:

```
      <?php if (!empty($primary_nav)): ?>
        <?php print render($primary_nav); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if (!empty($secondary_nav)): ?>
        <?php print render($secondary_nav); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I enforce this type of rendering from my module?

Since I am working on an ajax one pager site, I need to update the menu based on a user's role after login. A page reload would destroy the desired look and feel, and is therefore no option.

Currently I am using the following code to process the login:

```
function wr_pages_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_block' || $form_id == 'user_login') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'wr_login_form_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'user-login',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event' => 'click'
    );
  }
}

function wr_login_form_callback($form, $form_state) {
  if (!form_get_errors()) {
    return "<script>adjustViewsAndMenu();</script>";
  }
  else {
    return $form;
  }
}
```

adjustViewsAndMenu() makes changes to the menu, and adds extra parts to the one pager, depending on a user's role, however this function does not use any Drupal rendering, which is most likely not the best way to deal with this problem. Still haven't found out how to rerender a menu with AJAX while using the theme's rendering.

Comment: How are you handling the login?

Comment: I use hook_form_alter(), and a callback. I added the code in my question.